# Why is there an error when creating this block matrix/array? (SciPy and NumPy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np


def H1(M1, M2, N):
    row = [0, 1]
    col = [0, 0]
    data = [M1, M2]
    return sp.sparse.bsr_matrix((data, (row,col)), blocksize=(2,2), shape=(N,N)).toarray()


M1 = np.array([[1,1], [1,1]])
M2 = np.array([[2,2], [2,2]])
print(H1(M1, M2, 6))
```

```
line 248, in getnnz
    raise ValueError('row, column, and data arrays must be 1-D')
ValueError: row, column, and data arrays must be 1-D
```

I am not so sure why this error is occurring as bsr_matrix allows the data arrays to be 2-D. Any idea why?

The documentation shows that as long as the blocksize is defined it should work. Any idea why this error is occurring?

The main task I actually have is to iterate M1 along the diagonal and M2 below M1 for a 300 x 300 matrix. Anyone has a better idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [70]: data
Out[70]: 
[array([[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]),
 array([[2, 2],
        [2, 2]])] 
In [71]: row, col
Out[71]: ([0, 1], [0, 0])
In [72]: N=6
```

Your function call with FULL traceback:

```
In [73]: sparse.bsr_matrix((data, (row,col)), blocksize=(2,2), shape=(N,N))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[73], line 1
----> 1 sparse.bsr_matrix((data, (row,col)), blocksize=(2,2), shape=(N,N))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_bsr.py:157, in bsr_matrix.__init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy, blocksize)
    152     self.indptr = np.zeros(M//R + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    154 elif len(arg1) == 2:
    155     # (data,(row,col)) format
    156     self._set_self(
--> 157         self._coo_container(arg1, dtype=dtype, shape=shape).tobsr(
    158             blocksize=blocksize
    159         )
    160     )
    162 elif len(arg1) == 3:
    163     # (data,indices,indptr) format
    164     (data, indices, indptr) = arg1

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_coo.py:196, in coo_matrix.__init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
    193 if dtype is not None:
    194     self.data = self.data.astype(dtype, copy=False)
--> 196 self._check()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_coo.py:281, in coo_matrix._check(self)
    278 self.col = np.asarray(self.col, dtype=idx_dtype)
    279 self.data = to_native(self.data)
--> 281 if self.nnz > 0:
    282     if self.row.max() >= self.shape[0]:
    283         raise ValueError('row index exceeds matrix dimensions')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_base.py:299, in spmatrix.nnz(self)
    291 @property
    292 def nnz(self):
    293     """Number of stored values, including explicit zeros.
    294 
    295     See also
    296     --------
    297     count_nonzero : Number of non-zero entries
    298     """
--> 299     return self.getnnz()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_coo.py:248, in coo_matrix.getnnz(self, axis)
    243         raise ValueError('row, column, and data array must all be the '
    244                          'same length')
    246     if self.data.ndim != 1 or self.row.ndim != 1 or \
    247             self.col.ndim != 1:
--> 248         raise ValueError('row, column, and data arrays must be 1-D')
    250     return int(nnz)
    252 if axis < 0:

ValueError: row, column, and data arrays must be 1-D
```

The key is that with a 2 element `arg1`, it tries to make a `coo` matrix, and then convert that to `bsr`.  It does not treat the inputs in a special `bsr` fashion. The docs should be clearer.

```
self._coo_container(arg1, dtype=dtype, shape=shape).tobsr(
    158             blocksize=blocksize
```

Another way to put it, when it says `a[ij[0, k], ij[1, k]] = data[k]`, `data` is a 1d array of values, not a 3d array of n blocks.  So the `ij` values are the ordinary `coo` row and col.

If you want to provide blocks and block 'coordinates', you have to use the `csr` style of input.

`coo_matrix` has similar description, `A[i[k], j[k]] = data[k]`.  This supports the idea that `bsr_matrix((data, ij), [blocksize=(R,C), shape=(M, N)])` is just `coo_matrix((data,ij), shape=(M,N)).tobsr(blocksize=(R,C))`

---

Your description of iterate M1 on the diagonal etc. isn't obvious.  It almost sounds like you are trying to make:

```
In [74]: M=sparse.bmat([[M1,None,None],[M2,M1,None],[None,M2,M1]])

In [75]: M
Out[75]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 20 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [76]: M.A
Out[76]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

Converted to `bsr`, we can see what the `bsr_matrix` inputs should look like:

```
In [78]: Mb = M.tobsr(blocksize=(2,2))    
In [79]: Mb
Out[79]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 20 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>

In [80]: Mb.data
Out[80]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1]]], dtype=int32)

In [81]: Mb.indptr
Out[81]: array([0, 1, 3, 5], dtype=int32)

In [82]: Mb.indices
Out[82]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

There's also a block diagonal input:

In [83]: M1 = sparse.block_diag([M1,M1,M1], format='bsr')

In [84]: M1

```
Out[84]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 12 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>

In [85]: M1.data, M1.indptr, M1.indices
Out[85]: 
(array([[[1, 1],
         [1, 1]],
 
        [[1, 1],
         [1, 1]],
 
        [[1, 1],
         [1, 1]]], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32))

In [86]: M1.A
Out[86]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

You  might find the code for `sparse.bmat` to be instructive.  It constructs the `coo` versions of all the blocks, and then joins their `data,row,col` into 3 arrays, which are then used to make a new large `coo`.  `block_diag` also uses this collective `coo` method.

'raw' `coo` inputs were the original input form for sparse matrices, and remain the most basic style.  Years ago when I worked with FEM in MATLAB, efficiently constructing those three `coo` inputs was the biggest part of making the stiffness matrix.

### edit

The `csr` style input would be:

```
In [100]: M=sparse.bsr_matrix((data, [0,0],[0,1,2,2]),shape=(6,6))    
In [101]: M
Out[101]: 
<6x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 8 stored elements (blocksize = 2x2) in Block Sparse Row format>

In [102]: M.A
Out[102]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```